# Can someone identify this species?

Tags: species-identification

When I was about 5 or 6 years old, a tiny yellow puffball with 2 black spots which I think are eyes landed on my finger. I didn't dare breath, and after a few moments it flew away. Is there any such species that is similar to my description?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Given your description, it is very difficult to answer your question. Try to think of any feature you remember, any characteristic that might help the id. Maybe try to draw or post a picture that resembles what you have seen. As is, your question might be down-voted or closed as too broad.

Comment: Sounds like a bee/bumblebee covered in pollen.

Comment: It might be helpful to add location, season and daytime of the event.

Comment: It's really tiny, about 2 times the size of a pen point